# Why does this C Initialization Set Array Address To Zero?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, memory-address

Background:
MCU: MKL26Z128
IDE: Kinetis Design Studio 3.0.0

This code sets the address of usbStringDescriptors to zero.

```
uint8_t usbStringDescriptors[NUM_OF_STRING_DESCRIPTORS][MAX_BYTES_PER_USB_STRING] = {0};
uint8_t manStringDescriptor[MAX_BYTES_PER_USB_STRING] = {0};
```

...from the listing file

```
 225                .LFE57:
 227                    .global usbStringDescriptors
 228 001e C046          .section    .bss.usbStringDescriptors,"aw",%nobits
 229                    .align  2
 232                usbStringDescriptors:
 233 0000 00000000      .space  198
 233      00000000 
 233      00000000 
 233      00000000 
 233      00000000 
 234                    .global manStringDescriptor
 235 00c6 0000          .section    .bss.manStringDescriptor,"aw",%nobits
 236                    .align  2
 239                manStringDescriptor:
 240 0000 00000000      .space  66
```

...in the map file

```
 .bss.usbStringDescriptors
                0x00000000       0xc8 ./adapter/common/usb_core_ksdk/host/host_iAP.o
```

[image: bad]

---

This code does not.

```
uint8_t usbStringDescriptors[NUM_OF_STRING_DESCRIPTORS][MAX_BYTES_PER_USB_STRING];
uint8_t manStringDescriptor[MAX_BYTES_PER_USB_STRING];
```

...from the listing file

```
 225                .LFE57:
 227                    .comm   usbStringDescriptors,198,4
 228                    .comm   manStringDescriptor,66,4
```

[image: good]

Comment: It does not set the address, but all values to zero. Why do you think it was bad and the other good? Both are correct. What is your question?

Comment: becuase the first says =0 and the second doesnt?

Comment: MAX_BYTES_PER_USB_STRING must be 66, see the Type Field in the picture.

Comment: Why should the second code set the values to zero? You didn't ask for it unlike in the first code.

Comment: If you don't initialise the arrays, there is no guarantee what values they'll contain - could be random, could be all zero. That's why it's always a good idea to explicitly initialise things before you use them.

Comment: @ChrisTurner not _random_ but _undetermined_.

Comment: @ChrisTurner And it's not a _good idea_ to initialize things before using them. You _need_ to initialize them.

Comment: I could be way off here, but IIRC, initialized data goes in the .DATA section and uninitialized data goes in the .DATA? section. The latter is allocated at runtime. Maybe the graphic in the first one is showing the offset into the .DATA section.

Comment: The "value" is the address.  I don't want the address in RAM to be zero.  I do want them to be initialized to zero.

Comment: They're both global variables.  They are not allocated at runtime.

Comment: Just to clear up a point about the "value."  In the context in which they are shown, they're just pointers.  The "value" is the value of the pointer which is the address where the data is stored.

Comment: Since arrays are not pointers, it's impossible for an array to have 0 "value". If using an array which shows 0 as its value doesn't cause a crash, I'd say it's a problem with your debugger and you should ignore it.

Comment: I discovered this when I realized the values of the usbStringDescriptors were being corrupted, or worse, likely corrupting something else.  For some reason it's being placed at an invalid memory location.  I think that it could be due to the fact that I'm very nearly using all of the RAM on this chip, but I'm not sure why it would do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"In the context in which they are shown, they're just pointers."*? Do you mean that your debugger shows their addresses as if they were pointers pointing to them? Or do you mean that you have separate pointers with same names as your arrays which point to them?

Comment: I added a picture in which I expanded the arrays.  I'm saying in the first picture, they are essentially shown as pointers, hence the "value" is the address of the arrays to which they point.

Comment: Don't post images of text! Copy/paste the text as such and format it properly.

Comment: Could it be that the array is shown as `0` because it's optimised away? Is it still 0 if you use the array somehow? (Also, @Olaf, I don't think it matters in this case. He's using images to show us what his debugger shows; that's not code nor error logs.)

Comment: Could you show *all* the code you used to get that result? A complete example would help make sure it wasn't something else setting that pointer to null.

Comment: We need either compilable and executable code, or a crystal ball, and mine is currently out of use...

Comment: Is the presence of the initializer the *only* difference between the two versions?

Comment: To answer John's question... yes the presence of the initializer is literally the only difference between the two versions.  I build, debug and break at the main entry point of the application.  At that point I copy the values from the expressions window.  Then I make that single change, rebuild, debug and break at the main entry point of the application and take the next shot of the expressions window.  That's it.

Comment: IDK what's wrong with the pics, but I cannot even see anything, or is that white text on white background?!

Comment: I can't format a table, so the screen grab of the expressions window seemed like the next best thing.

Comment: @MattJohnson: I have to think there's UB somewhere else in your code that's overwriting whatever the debugger is looking at, and it manifests this way only when you explicitly initialize the array.  We'd need to see the actual code, not just the declarations.  Dollars to donuts you're writing past the end of an array somewhere.

Comment: What I meant was an initialized array becomes part of the exe file, but there's no need for an uninitialized array to bloat the exe. The OS can allocate that space when it loads the exe. You don't specify compiler/platform but it appears it is representing initialized arrays as an offset and uninitialized as addresses.

Comment: I added some info to the initial post.  I also removed the expanded picture, because it seemed to cause more confusion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136901/discussion-on-question-by-matt-johnson-why-does-this-c-initialization-set-array).

Answer (score 0):

Since these arrays have static storage, it makes virtually no difference whether you put the `{0}` initializer or not.  By the time control reaches the `main()` function, they would be initialized to `0`.

- If you put the initializer, the data might be present in the executable file, making it larger and potentially slower to load,
- If you don't, the data will located in the *uninitialized* segment (also called bss or common section) and will be initialized to 0 by the loader in a normal environment.

The second option is preferred for the reasons explained above.